# Add combobox control in column with same datasource without creating object each time(telerik,c#)

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-grid

I am using telerik Radgrid to display my data .My aim is to add specific column with combobox of each row with same datasource without creating object each time,Because i have to create object combobox each time even if the datasource is same. Is this possible in Telerik?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you adding the combobox dynamically?

Comment: No i want to add same combobox to specific row cell.

Comment: Use a `GridTemplateColumn` to add a combobox to each row. Then set the datasourceID in the control.